# Why does numpy.ndarray allow for a "None" array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nonetype, numpy-ndarray

I was wondering what is the rationale for the following functionality of `numpy.ndarray`:

```
>>> a = None
>>> a = np.asarray(a)
array(None, dtype=object)

>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> a == None
True

>>> a is None
False
```

So in this case Python seems to actually create a `None` array (not array of Nones), which seems to enforce a type over variable `a`. But the documentation states that the positional argument needs to be "array_like":

> a : array_like
>
> > Input data, in any form that can be converted to an array. This includes lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples of lists and ndarrays.

So why is `None` accepted as "array-like" since it is not any of the listed above?

By analogy, `list(None)` will return error because `None` is not "iterable" as per documentation.

Furthermore, some functions seem to actually return seemingly incorrect values. For example `np.ndarray.argmax()` or `np.ndarray.argmin()` actually return 0 for a "None array", but result in an error for an empty array which intuitively seems like the expected behaviour.

```
>>> a
array(None, dtype=object)
>>> b
array([], dtype=object)
>>> a.argmax()
0
>>> b.argmax()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
```

Is there actually any advantage to having a "None array" (`array(None, dtype=object)`) as opposed to an empty array (`array([], dtype=object)`)?

Is this an intended functionality, or accidental consequence of `Nones` being actual objects? Could someone explain what's going on under the bonnet here and why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `np.array(3)` also works - that is, `np.array` accepts a scalar as well.  Pay attention to the `shape` and `dtype` in cases like this.  As for which functions work, beware to 3 possible problems - the `()` shape, the `object` dtype, and `None` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are getting with `np.asarray(None)` is an array with shape `()`, which is a [scalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html), with dtype `object`. You get something similar if you do `np.asarray(2)` or `np.asarray('abc')`. Scalars cannot be iterated but can be compared to non-NumPy values. At the same time, you get NumPy operations with them, so you can do:

```
list(np.asarray(None).reshape((1,)))
```

And it works.

About functions like `argmin` or `argmax`. Note that a scalar is not empty. An array with shape `()` has one element, yet zero dimensions, while an array with shape `(0,)` has no elements but one dimension. This may be counterintuitive but it makes sense and makes things work too. As documented, `argmin` and `argmax`, when no `axis` value is given, work on the flattened array. The flattened array for a scalar (e.g. `np.asarray(None).ravel()`) is an array with shape `(1,)`, and, since you are asking for the index of the smallest or greatest value and it only has one value, the answer is `0` in both cases. Interestingly, if you try `np.argmin(np.asarray([None, None]))` it fails, because now you have two elements and you need to compare them to know which one is the smallest, but you cannot compare `None` values.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your answer!

However in terms of the ```argmin``` and ```argmax``` functions:

If I end up specifying the axis parameter (and thus not performing the operation on the flattened array with a single element), it still returns the index of 0 which seems counterintuitive, mainly because specifying axis indicates a dimension (is that right?), while the ```array(None, dtype=object)``` or ```array(3, dtype=int)``` have, as you mentioned, shape ```()```, which indicates no dimensions.

Comment: @jolaem You're right that using `argmin` / `argmax` with `axis=0` still works with scalars, which, being picky, I think should be an error, because indeed the argument does not have such axis. Using any other axis value fails, so I suppose the code is treating similarly scalars and 1D arrays at some point. I suppose you could also argue these functions should not work at all, because scalars are not arrays at all... only they are `numpy.ndarray` objects, so they do behave more like an array than you might expect from a scalar, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering what is the rationale for the following functionality of numpy.ndarray:

NumPy allows 0-dimensional arrays, and it allows arrays of `object` dtype. Together, these facts mean that any object can be interpreted as a 0-dimensional array-like of `object` dtype, and that's how `numpy.array` will interpret any argument it can't find some other way to interpret. That's what's happening here.

What you have is a 0-dimensional, 1-element array whose 1 element is None.

```
In [12]: x = numpy.array(None)
In [13]: x.shape
Out[13]: ()
In [14]: x.size
Out[14]: 1
In [15]: print(x.item())
None
```

> So in this case Python seems to actually create a None array (not array of Nones)

No, it is an array of Nones. It is an array of exactly one None. You can access the None by providing a tuple of no indices, or by calling the `item()` method, or in a bunch of other ways.

```
In [15]: print(x.item())
None
In [16]: print(x[()])
None
```

> So why is None accepted as "array-like" since it is not any of the listed above?

The list is not intended to be exhaustive.

> Furthermore, some functions seem to actually return seemingly incorrect values. For example np.ndarray.argmax() or np.ndarray.argmin() actually return 0 for a "None array", but result in an error for an empty array which intuitively seems like the expected behaviour.

If you don't provide an `axis` argument, `argmax` and `argmin` default to working over a flattened form of the input. `0` is the index of the only element of the flattened form of your 0-dimensional array.

```
In [23]: y = x.ravel()
In [24]: y
Out[24]: array([None], dtype=object)
In [25]: y.argmin()
Out[25]: 0
In [26]: y.argmax()
Out[26]: 0
In [27]: print(y[0])
None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Mostly makes sense but a follow up question on the ```argmax```. If I specify ```axis``` parameter and thus not working on a flattened array, I still get the index 0 from ```np.array(None).argmax(axis=0)```, which seems counterintuitive because ```np.array(None)``` has shape of ```()``` and so no dimensions, while the ```axis``` parameter indicates a dimension. Why is that?

Comment: @jolaem: Historical mistake and backward compatibility, probably.

Comment: Yeah so it seems, thanks a lot for your explanation!